# correccion programa java

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en esto de programar con `Java`, y no se que similitudes tenga con `C`, si alguien puede corregidme el programa se lo agradecería el objetivo del programa es calcular una factura de supermercado. Cuando le doy **run** solo sale el final del programa con el mensaje **"el valor de su factura es:0.0".**

El que pueda resolver mi duda por favor que me diga donde esta mi error o errores.

```
package punto.pkg3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Punto3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner entrada=new Scanner (System.in);

    double a=0;

    double b=0;

    double c=0;

    double d=0;

    double e=0;

    double f=0;

    double g=0;

    while (a==1) {

    System.out.println("hay mas productos?");

        System.out.println("1=si, 2 =no");

         a=entrada.nextDouble();

        while (a!=1 | a!=2){

            System.out.println("no es un valor valido, vuelva a digitar");

         a=entrada.nextDouble();

        }

        System.out.println("digite el valor del producto");

        b=entrada.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("cuantas unidades llevo de este producto?");

        c=entrada.nextDouble();

        d=b*c;

        e=d+(d*16/100);

        if(e>=50000)

            e=e-(e*5/100);

        else

            break;

      f=f+e;

    }

    System.out.println("el valor de su factura es:" +f);
}

}
```

Comment: te voy a proporcionar un ejemplo utilizando uan clase que llamare producto, simple y muy clara. Un segundo y te lo hago

Comment: El `while` lo utilizas para a = 1, y anteriormente declaras a = 0, jamás va a entrar al `while`, sería recomendable usar un `do while`, además de otras mejoras al programa

Comment: Nunca se va a ejecutar tu bucle porque `a == 1` siempre es falso ya que a la variable `a` le has asignado el valor `0`.

Comment: ya lo corregi y corre bien, pero no hace las operaciones, sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje al final.
Ademas el bucle no se repite, solo se hace una vez

Answer (score 1):

En efecto como ya lo indico @Xam tienes varios errores referentes a los operadores logicos, esta seccion esta bien:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Punto3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner entrada=new Scanner (System.in);
```

Despues al asignar un valor inicial de "0" para la variable "a", nunca ingresara a tu bucle, por lo que asignariamos un valor de 1

```
double a=1;
double b=0;
double c=0;
double d=0;
double e=0;
double f=0;
double g=0;
```

Ahora si, podemos ingresar al bucle

```
while (a==1) {

 System.out.println("hay mas productos?");
 System.out.println("1=si, 2 =no");
 a=entrada.nextDouble();
```

Sin embargo el segundo bucle tambien es incorrecto si tu indicas que evalue que "a" sea diferente de 1 o sea diferente de 2, esto siempre sera cierto, por ejemplo si a=1 entonces sera diferente de 2 y el bucle se ciclara infinitamente, lo mismo sucede si "a" es 2, o cualquier otro valor, sugiero que lo cambies por esto:

```
while (a<1 || a>2){
   System.out.println("no es un valor valido, vuelva a digitar");
   a=entrada.nextDouble();
}
```

Ahora ya que se aseguro que "a" tiene un valor de 1 o 2, romperiamos el ciclo en caso de que al valor sea 2, con esto ya no es necesario el "else break" de la parte final del codigo

```
if (a==2) break;
```

El resto del codigo es correcto

```
System.out.println("digite el valor del producto");
b=entrada.nextDouble();

System.out.println("cuantas unidades llevo de este producto?");
c=entrada.nextDouble();

    d=b*c;
    e=d+(d*16/100);

    if(e>=50000)
        e=e-(e*5/100);

    f=f+e;

   }

   System.out.println("el valor de su factura es:" +f);
 }

}
```

Comment: no se porque el programa no hace las operaciones, me dice que el resultado de la factura es es 0 y no me pedi el resto de productos

Comment: Y ya hiciste las correcciones que te mencione?, porque yo ya lo comprobe y si me funciona...

Comment: si, ya pude, un pequeño error que tenia, con estos codigos uno no se puede descuidar jajaja, cualquier cosa pequeña y se daña todo.
en todo caso, muchas gracias.

Comment: Excelente, que bien que te haya sido util.

Answer (score 0):

> Disculpa la tardanza, pero me salio un imprevisto. Aqui tienes algo parecido a lo que querias. Si tienes alguna duda dime en los comentarios y si te ha solucionado el problema pues podria indicar mi respuesta como correcta para ayudar a mas gente. Un saludo.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class producto {

    private String nombre;
    private double precio;

    public producto(String nombre, double precio) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public void print() {

        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        System.out.println("Nombre: " + getNombre());
        System.out.println("Precio: " + getPrecio() +" euros");
    }

}

public class Producto_cesta {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<producto> cesta_productos = new ArrayList();

        boolean continuar = true;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String repetir = "s";

        while ("s".equals(repetir)) {

            try {

                System.out.println("Introduce el nomrbe del prodcuto");
                System.out.print("-> ");
                String nombre = br.readLine();

                System.out.println("Introduce el precio del prodcuto");
                System.out.print("-> ");
                double precio = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());

                cesta_productos.add(new producto(nombre, precio));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error al introcudir los datos del producto = " + e);
            }

            repetir = "no se aun";
            while (!"s".equals(repetir) && !"n".equals(repetir)) {
                System.out.println("¿Quieres añadir un nuevo producto (s/n)?");
                System.out.print("->");
                try {
                    repetir = br.readLine();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error Lectura = " + e);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("#################################33");

        System.out.println("Los productos que has ingresado");
        double precio_total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cesta_productos.size(); i++) {
            producto p = cesta_productos.get(i);
            p.print();
            precio_total += p.getPrecio();
        }
        System.out.println("===================================");
        System.out.println("PRECIO TOTAL = "+precio_total+" euros");
    }

}
```